# how do I disconnect inactive clients with TIdTCPServer?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-xe8

I am trying to disconnect inactive clients that are connected to `TIdTCPServer`, whether those clients are disconnected from their Internet or for a period of inactive time.

I tried to set timeouts in the `OnConnect` event like the following:

```
procedure TservForm.TcpServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 26000;
  AContext.Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDTIMEO, 15000);
end;
```

But it seems a disconnect is not triggered after the client connection is lost.

I tried to use `SetKeepAliveValues()`, but it takes too much time to get an inactive client disconnected.

Is there a more helpful way to disconnect inactive clients? So if the client did not receive or send anything, for example in 30 seconds, the server will disconnect it?

on execute event

```
procedure TservForm.TcpServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
  cmd: String;
  Cache, OutboundCmds: TStringList;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  I: integer;
  S: String;
begin
  Connection := AContext as TConnection;

  // check for pending outbound commands...
  OutboundCmds := nil;
  try
    Cache := Connection.OutboundCache.Lock;
    try
      if Cache.Count > 0 then
      begin
        OutboundCmds := TStringList.Create;
        OutboundCmds.Assign(Cache);
        Cache.Clear;
      end;
    finally
      Connection.OutboundCache.Unlock;
    end;

    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
      begin
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Writeln(OutboundCmds.Strings[I],
          IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
        MS := TMemoryStream(OutboundCmds.Objects[I]);
        if MS <> nil then
        begin
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := true;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(MS, 0, true);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
        OutboundCmds.Objects[I].Free;
    end;
    OutboundCmds.Free;
  end;

  // check for a pending inbound command...
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
    Exit;
    end;
  end;

  cmd := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);

  ...............
  ...............
```

Comment: What does your `OnExecute` event handler look like? The timeouts you are using depend on the kind of I/O you are performing. Also, `SetKeepAliveValues()` does work to detect dead connections (but not inactive connections), though not all platforms support customizing the keepalive timeout intervals. Another option would be to run a worker thread that monitors the connections and closes their sockets after inactive timeouts have elapsed. You can use the `TIdContext.Data` property to track the last send/receive time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau on execute added , on client side i set timer to send command to server each 10 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client does not disconnect because the `ReadLn()` is not reached during idle times, so the `ReadTimeout` does not have effect, and if you are not sending a lot of commands then the socket buffer is not filling up so `SO_SNDTIMEO` does not have an effect, either.

Since you are already doing some manual timeout handling, you can expand on it to handle an idle timeout as well, eg:

```
type
  TConnection = class(TIdServerContext)
    ...
  public
    LastSendRecv: LongWord;
    ...
  end;

...

procedure TservForm.TcpServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
begin
  Connection := AContext as TConnection;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 30000;
  AContext.Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDTIMEO, 15000);
  Connection.LastSendRecv := Ticks;
end; 

procedure TservForm.TcpServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
  cmd: String;
  Cache, OutboundCmds: TStringList;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  I: integer;
  S: String;
begin
  Connection := AContext as TConnection;

  // check for pending outbound commands...
  OutboundCmds := nil;
  try
    Cache := Connection.OutboundCache.Lock;
    try
      if Cache.Count > 0 then
      begin
        OutboundCmds := TStringList.Create;
        OutboundCmds.Assign(Cache);
        Cache.Clear;
      end;
    finally
      Connection.OutboundCache.Unlock;
    end;

    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
      begin
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(OutboundCmds.Strings[I]);
        MS := TMemoryStream(OutboundCmds.Objects[I]);
        if MS <> nil then               
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(MS, 0, true);    
      end;
      Connection.LastSendRecv := Ticks;
    end;
  finally
    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
        OutboundCmds.Objects[I].Free;
    end;
    OutboundCmds.Free;
  end;

  // check for a pending inbound command...
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      if GetTickDiff(Connection.LastSendRecv, Ticks) >= 30000 then
        AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  cmd := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;    
  Connection.LastSendRecv := Ticks;

  ...
end;
```

Comment: where is TIdTicks declared at ?

Comment: hmm i added idglobal in uses but its undeclared

Comment: Then you are using an older version of Indy 10.  `TIdTicks`, `Ticks64()`, and `GetEalpsedTicks()` were added 2 years ago.  In your case, you can use `Ticks()` instead, since your timeout will not exceed the 49.7 day limit of `LongWord`.

Comment: i am using indy that comes with xe 8 not sure because if the upgrade from xe 7 , should i change the variable from Tidticks `LastsendRCv : LongWord; ` and use Ticks function instead ?

Comment: is this can cause server crash ? because after adding those lines to onconnect event my server start to crash when some clients entered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127327/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-vlark-lopin).

Comment: i have to say this code work perfect , after reinstall my IDE no deadlock issue at all i think it was something with my indy version . after clean installation the server works normal 100%